# Crash here SDK Navigate - Google Analytics

Tags: here-api

I see a log of this crash and I have no idea how to trouble shoot it. Any guidance ?
I use the flutter navigate SDK 4.12.11.0361

Crash : OLPSDKPOOL_6
SIGABRT ABORT 0x00000001cbe9c200

keyboard_arrow_up
0
libsystem_kernel.dylib
__pthread_kill + 8
5arrow_drop_down
libsystem_malloc.dylib
find_zone_and_free + 308
arrow_right 6
heresdk
here_sdk_sdk_venue_threading_VenueThreads_get_type_id + 19512588
7
heresdk
here_sdk_sdk_venue_threading_VenueThreads_get_type_id + 24067388

I am not clear on how to trouble shoot this.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow below steps  for Troubleshooting.

When you run into trouble, please make sure to first check the minimum requirements and the supported devices.

- Xcode does not compile my project for simulators. I am using a computer with a M1 chip. You are using a HERE SDK version below 4.9.2.0. Try to use a newer HERE SDK version or run in Rosetta mode by excluding the arm64 architecture for "Any iOS Simulator SDK" in the Build Settings/Architectures/Excluded Architectures/Debug setting within Xcode. Select this option in the "TARGETS" settings. Note that this may slightly slow down the performance when running the simulator.
- I see only a blank white map: Make sure that your HERE credentials are valid and set as described in the Get Started section above. Also, make sure that your device is able to make an internet connection. With slower internet connections, it may take a while until you see the first map tiles loaded. Please also make sure that your device time is set correctly. In rare cases, a wrongly set device time can lead to authentication issues with some backend services.
- I see only a blank white map: Make sure that your HERE credentials are valid and set as described in the Get Started section above. Also, make sure that your device is able to make an internet connection. With slower internet connections, it may take a while until you see the first map tiles loaded. Please also make sure that your device time is set correctly. In rare cases, a wrongly set device time can lead to authentication issues with some backend services.
- The app crashes and in the logs I see "CL_magma - Couldn't load the default shader.":
- I am seeing the following in a crash log: "Exception was thrown in Java and it was not handled.": The HERE SDK cannot handle runtime exceptions that are thrown on app side inside a callback. In such a case you will see this error log. It means that your code throws an exception in one of the HERE SDK callbacks that are handled by your application.
- I see a gray screen: If the logs repeatedly say "dequeueBuffer failed", then this is caused by a Flutter issue that might get fixed by a new Flutter version, eventually Flutter 1.20.3.

The same details are there in the below link.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.13.2.0/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html#troubleshooting